# indexing large MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am a bit lost on indexing a large table. The thing is I need to query it using a lot of different filters. So for example in a table:

```
id | key_1 | key_2 | ... | key_n
```

There might be a filter for one or multiple keys, each adding(I am using Zend framework to build queries using prepared statements):

```
$select->where($this->_db->quoteInto('key_n = ?', $filter->key_n));
```

If I understand correctly to speed up the query I should index some of the columns. So it prompted a couple of questions:

- Does it make sense to add indexes to all the columns that will be used to filter the data?
- If I will index a lot of columns, how will it affect the speed with which the data is written to the table?
- Does it make sense to add indexes with combination of the columns?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640699/in-mysql-does-putting-select-foo-increase-in-performance-if-foo-is-indexed?rq=1 and also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168518/mysql-should-i-make-all-columns-in-my-table-indexed?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The link @bodi0 posted has some of the answers. But I will add the following:

> Does it make sense to add indexes to all the columns that will be used
>   to filter the data?

Maybe. Usually, an index does speed up data retrieval. But in some cases it doesn't: If the [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29) of the indexed column is low the index may provide none or so little benefit that the optimizer may decide to ignore it. Think of a column "gender" for example with only two values "M" or "F". If each applies to about 50% of the rows an index may provide little improvement. Or, if 75% of the records are "M" and you're querying for "M" the index will most likely not be used at all.

> Does it make sense to add indexes with combination of the columns?

Maybe. If you know that a certain combination of columns will often be used to filter in a single `SELECT` such an index may prove beneficial. Note though that for the index to be usable, its first column(s) must be in the filter criteria. For example: An index on columns `(gender, state)` can only be used when `gender` (and optionally `state`) is used as criteria in the query. If only `state` is filtered by the index will not be used.

Then, given that MySQL uses only a single index per query to a table, a composite index may really make sense because without it only one indexed column can be used by the DB engine.